# How to control Charka UI accordion item expansion?

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

In the [Chakra docs](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/accordion/usage) they provide an example but I can't get it to work.

I want to control the expansion of the second accordion item, index 1. I can control its disabled state using `isDisabled` prop like this:

```
const [disableNd, setDisableNd] = useState(false);

<Button onClick={() => setDisableNd(!disableNd)}>
    Expand 2nd
 </Button>
 
<Accordion allowToggle>
  //..
  <AccordionItem isDisabled={disableNd}>
    //...
  </AccordionItem>
</Accordion>
```

But when I do the same with `isExpanded` prop or use the example they have in docs I can't get it to work. How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Accordion page from Chakra UI docs](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/accordion/usage#accessing-the-internal-state):

> If you need access to the internal state of each accordion item, you can use a render prop. It provides 2 internal state props: isExpanded and isDisabled.

It means that the `isExpanded` prop is only useful to get the state of an accordion item.

In order to expand one or more items, you have to use the `index` prop on the `Accordion` component:

> `index`: The index(es) of the expanded accordion item

```
const [accordionIndex, setAccordionIndex] = useState(-1);

<Button onClick={() => setAccordionIndex(1)}>
  Expand 2nd
</Button>
 
<Accordion allowToggle index={accordionIndex}>
  //..
  <AccordionItem>
    //...
  </AccordionItem>
</Accordion>
```

It is important to note that the `index` prop has to be an array to expand more than one item:

```
<Accordion index={[0, 1]}>
  //...
</Accordion>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the internal state you should use a render prop.

To do that, add this line inside the AccordionItem: {({ isExpanded }) and wrap all the content of it.

The code should be like this:

```
<Accordion allowToggle>
  <AccordionItem>
     {({ isExpanded }) => (
       <>
         <AccordionButton>
            {isExpanded && "This accordion is expanded"}
         </AccordionButton>
         <AccordionPanel pb={4}>
                //...
         </AccordionPanel>
       </>
     )}
  </AccordionItem>
</Accordion>
```